# Angular CDK Drag and Drop won't work after updating component's HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular8

I have a fresh system of Angular 8. There's one *Module* with one *Component*:

```
ng new my-app --enable-ivy
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
npm install --save hammerjs
```

In the *Module* I'm adding:

```
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
```

and also:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DragDropModule
  ]
})
```

In the *Component's* HTML I added this:

```
<div cdkDrag>
  Drag me around!
</div>
```

Now I serve the site using:

```
ng serve --port 4300
```

And voila, I can drag the item around.

---

However, when I update anything of the *Component's* HTML and the page refreshes, I can't drag the element anymore. The text changes are reflected for example. But the the drag functionality is gone.

When I restart the server on the CLI it works again, until I udate the markup.

This doesn't happen when I change the *Component's* TypeScript-file, only when the HTML is altered.

What is the problem?

Comment: did u try to off ivy in config file and check again?

Comment: @НикитаСереда Oh boy, that fixes it. Is the CDK not compatible with Ivy yet?

Comment: Ivy at this moment in state "opt in preview". That means not all functional works fine. U Can submit issue in their github channel) In my case after up to v8.0.3 i have problems with FormGroup & AbstractControl... W8ing then they fix them =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with Angular 8.0. Updating to Angular 8.2 and the corresponding Angular Material CDK package solved the problem.